# Animating 3 DIV's onClick

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

I have 3 DIV's, each 33.3333%, which should be animated by click.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left" class="links">LINKS</div>
<div id="middle" class="mitte">MITTE</div>
<div id="right" class="rechts">RECHTS</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

The clicked DIV should increase to 60%, the both others should shrink to 20%.

But I haven't any jQuery skills so I've searched in the Net for solutions. The only solution I've found was with hover and not with click.

```
    $("#left, #middle, #right").each(function() {
    $(this).data("standardWidth", $(this).width());
});

$("#left, #middle, #right").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "60%"
    }, 300 );
    $(this).parent().children().not(this).animate({
        width: "20%"
    }, 300 );
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().children().each(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).data("standardWidth")
        }, 300 );
    });
});
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7E35x/1/) with the hover it works fine, but how can I change it to click?

Is anybody out there who can help?

Thanks in Advance

Thorsten

Comment: `$("#left, #middle, #right").click(...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to :

```
$("#left, #middle, #right").each(function () {
    $(this).data("standardWidth", $(this).width());
});

$("#left, #middle, #right").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "60%"
    }, 300);
    $(this).parent().children().not(this).animate({
        width: "20%"
    }, 300);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7E35x/2/)**

All I did was change `hover` to `click` and remove the second function.

And here's a **[second version](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7E35x/4/)** that will allow a second click to restore the original widths.

```
$("#left, #middle, #right").each(function () {
    $(this).data("standardWidth", $(this).width());
});
$("#left, #middle, #right").click(function () {
    if ($(this).data('active')) {
        $(this).parent().children().each(function () {
            $(this).animate({
                width: $(this).data("standardWidth")
            }, 300);
        });
        $(this).data('active', 0);
    } else {
        $('#wrapper div').data('active', 0);
        $(this).data('active', 1);
        $(this).animate({
            width: "60%"
        }, 300);
        $(this).parent().children().not(this).animate({
            width: "20%"
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great!!! This works fantastic. Is it also possible to resize the DIV's to "normal" by clicking again?

Comment: My second example should do that.

Comment: Thanks j08691...it was my fault. It was copied, but not the complete code. Now it works properly in jsFiddle. Any idea why I can't get it run in Wordpress? Other JS works perfect.

Comment: To the cowardly anonymous downvoter, care to explain yourself? Grow a pair or remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Change .hover to .click and it will work.

Comment: This was my first try, but nothing happens if I click on a DIV.